# html5 localstorage and web sql storage

Tags: html, local-storage

I would like to know if html5 localstorage has anything to do with web sql storage.

Can you for example create a localstorage object and make queries on it using the web sql storage syntax?

Also, what is the difference between indexedDB and web sql storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation other than they can store data locally.

- LocalStorage is simple key/value store
- WebSQL has been deprecated and is not going forward
- IndexedDB is a JSON object document store replacing WebSQL.

Comment: I think IndexedDB is not mandated to be JSON, can actually be implemented with SQL if a browser vendor decides to do it that way. But that's the beauty of it, it's abstracting the database interface.

Comment: The internals are just that :-) The API dictates you store some kind of object and as it's a JavaScript API. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-put-IDBRequest-any-value-any-key